# Sinatra server response timeout

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a sinatra app which has a `get` route. It does quite a bit of work and hence takes about a minute to finish the task. When I try to `curl` it everything works fine but I don't get the response code back or anything for that matter. `curl` times out and if I try it on the browser it times out as well. And also both time out in 30 sec.

I have been trying to find a way to increase the server timeout. Any leads?

Comment: I did realize that the thin server timeout is defaulted to 30 but I am not sure how to override this in my app

Comment: Note that 30 seconds is too much for users to wait. You should make it faster or use a nicer UI with something like a progress bar.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that there's a way to pass settings to the server used by Sinatra using:

```
set :server_settings, :timeout => 60
```

So if you're using **thin**, you can use the timeout setting as described by Fábio Perez.

There's a discussion about this setting in [GitHub](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/940) **so you should read it** if you decide to choose using it.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, and I found two solutions to it:

- Explicitly running the `thin` server removed the response timeout.
- Streaming the response kept the connection open, even if I was only streaming meaningless white space characters during processing.

### Reproducing the problem

Here's a trivial example script I created to show the problem:

```
# my_app.rb
require 'json'
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/process/:count' do
  count = params[:count].to_i
  count.times do
    sleep 10
  end
  "Processed #{count} items.".to_json
end
```

I launch that by calling `ruby my_app.rb`.

It represents the effort to process each item by sleeping for 10 seconds.

If I process two items with a `curl` request, it responds successfully after 20 seconds. If I try to process four items, the server closes the connection after 30 seconds.

```
$ date ; curl http://localhost:4567/process/2 ; echo ; date
Fri Mar 18 11:35:00 PDT 2016
"Processed 2 items."
Fri Mar 18 11:35:20 PDT 2016
$ date ; curl http://localhost:4567/process/4 ; echo ; date
Fri Mar 18 11:35:28 PDT 2016
curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Fri Mar 18 11:35:58 PDT 2016
```

### Running with thin

I added a rackup configuration file in the same directory as `my_app.rb`:

```
# config.ru (run with rackup)
require './my_app'
run Sinatra::Application
```

Then I run the server like this:

```
thin -R config.ru start
```

Now it doesn't seem to have any response timeout.

```
$ date ; curl http://localhost:3000/process/2 ; echo ; date
Fri Mar 18 13:18:43 PDT 2016
"Processed 2 items."
Fri Mar 18 13:19:03 PDT 2016
$ date ; curl http://localhost:3000/process/4 ; echo ; date
Fri Mar 18 13:19:08 PDT 2016
"Processed 4 items."
Fri Mar 18 13:19:48 PDT 2016
```

### Streaming response

If you can't change the way you launch the server, you can fix the problem by switching to a streaming response and returning a space before processing each item. The leading spaces shouldn't break JSON or HTML responses.

```
# my_app2.rb
require 'json'
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'

get '/process/:count' do
  count = params[:count].to_i
  stream do |out|
    count.times do
      out << " "
      sleep 10
    end
    out << "Processed #{count} items.".to_json
  end
end
```

Now the server leaves the connection open.

```
$ date ; curl http://localhost:4567/process/2 ; echo ; date
Fri Mar 18 11:37:23 PDT 2016
  "Processed 2 items."
Fri Mar 18 11:37:43 PDT 2016
$ date ; curl http://localhost:4567/process/4 ; echo ; date
Fri Mar 18 11:37:48 PDT 2016
    "Processed 4 items."
Fri Mar 18 11:38:28 PDT 2016
```